# In Java, why does this array declaration compile?

Tags: java

I noticed this in my correctly-compiled Java code today :

```
int[] content = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,};
```

There's an extra comma at the end, after `15`  - so I was curious as to whether this is an intended thing in Java.  Why doesn't the compiler raise an error here?

Comment: Yet another abomination in Java; in my humble opinion of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Java language specification, [section 10.6: Array initializers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf):

> A trailing comma may appear after the last expression in an array initializer and
>   is ignored.

Speculation: This makes it easy to remove items in a multi-line initializer by commenting out any line, even the last one.

```
String[] NAMES = new String[] {
    "Shaggy",
    "Scooby",
    "Fred",
    "Velma",
    "Daphne",
//  "Scrappy Doo" 
}
```

Comment: I can see how that'd be convenient ,  Thanks  !!

Comment: Your speculation is right. In the book "The Java Programming Language" (Arnold-Gosling-Holmes), the authors state specifically that *This is a convenience for multiline initializers so you can reorder, add or remove values without having to remember to add a comma to the old last line, or remove it from the new last line*.

Answer (score 2):

It is ignored as per [this section of the language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6):

> An array initializer is written as a comma-separated list of expressions, enclosed by braces { and }.
>
> **A trailing comma may appear after the last expression in an array initializer and is ignored.**